# Converting Bitmap PixelFormats in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image

I need to convert a Bitmap from `PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb` to `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`.

I was hoping to use Bitmap.Clone, but it does not seem to be working.

```
Bitmap orig = new Bitmap("orig.bmp");
Bitmap clone = orig.Clone(new Rectangle(0,0,orig.Width,orig.Height), PixelFormat.Format24bppArgb);
```

If I run the above code and then check clone.PixelFormat it is set to `PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb`. What is going on/how do I convert the format?

Comment: Does this only happen on XP? I found the problem on XP but it seems to work fine on Windows 7. Hans' solution fixed it for me.

Comment: That's kind of funny. I have a solution that works fine on XP but breaks, giving this error, on Windows 7...

Comment: I can confirm that only XP is affected.

Comment: You should watch out on systems that aren't XP too. I haven't tested this spesific code, but working on the pixel level when comparing two images on Windows 7 I ran into a similar problem that was caused from this bug/feature. Dan7 explained exactly what is happening and a more general approach to fixing it.

Comment: [This](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_ImageExtensions_ConvertPixelFormat_1.htm) works on all platforms (disclaimer: written by me). Can be downloaded as a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Sloppy, not uncommon for GDI+.  This fixes it:

```
Bitmap orig = new Bitmap(@"c:\temp\24bpp.bmp");
Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(orig.Width, orig.Height,
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone)) {
    gr.DrawImage(orig, new Rectangle(0, 0, clone.Width, clone.Height));
}

// Dispose orig as necessary...
```

Comment: I had a similar issue to the OP, except I had problems with a 48BppRgb TIFF that was saved as 32BppArgb PNG. GDI+ couldn't convert properly and the resulting image was very dark. This solution allowed me to solve that problem by manually redrawing the image as 32BppRgb, so +1.

Answer (score 38):

For some reason if you create a `Bitmap` from a file path, i.e. `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("myimage.jpg");`, and call `Clone()` on it, the returned `Bitmap` will not be converted.

However if you create another `Bitmap` from your old `Bitmap`, `Clone()` will work as intended.

Try something like this:

```
using (Bitmap oldBmp = new Bitmap("myimage.jpg"))
using (Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(oldBmp))
using (Bitmap targetBmp = newBmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, newBmp.Width, newBmp.Height), PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
{
    // targetBmp is now in the desired format.
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks Dan7 for explaining what the trigger was. I've seen `new Bitmap(new Bitmap("image.jpg"))` before but didn't know why it worked.

Comment: is there an easy way to `Clone` and convert all the pages of the bitmap ? I've noticed that `targtBmp` only has the active frame in `oldBmp`.

Comment: This better than marked "Solution" - it's worked with Indexed PixelFormat 4bpp, 8bpp

Answer (score 8):

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppArgb))
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
  g.DrawImage(..);
}
```

Should work like that. Maybe you want to set some parameters on `g` to define the interpolation mode for quality etc.

Comment: InterpolationMode is for scaling, i don't really think that he wants to scale it. Maybe do something like bmp.SetResolution(old.HorizontalResolution, old.VerticalResolution) and call g.DrawImageUnscaled(old, 0,0). But its just my opinion :)

Comment: @Elmue - do you have any reference to your statement?MSDN states other..