# How to convert between PIxelFormat?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting Bitmap PixelFormats in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016406/converting-bitmap-pixelformats-in-c)

How to convert a Bitmap with different PixelFormat to the PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb format?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use next

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(yourImage.Width, yourImage.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    gr.DrawImage(yourImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, yourImage.Width, yourImage.Height));
```

bmp - will have 16 bit quality. Specify `PixelFormat` to what you want