# Why GC is making fail the following code snippet

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, unmanaged

I'm a little bit confusing about how .NET manages images, I have the following code, to build a managed bitmap form an unmanaged HBitmap, perserving the alpha channel.

```
    public static Bitmap GetBitmapFromHBitmap(IntPtr nativeHBitmap)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(nativeHBitmap);

        if (Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(bmp.PixelFormat) < 32)
            return bmp;

        BitmapData bmpData;

        if (IsAlphaBitmap(bmp, out bmpData))
        {
            // MY QUESTION IS RELATED TO THIS
            // IF CALL SUPPRESS_FINALIZE THE OBJECT
            // IT WILL WORK, OTHERWISE IT FAILS
            GC.SuppressFinalize(bmp);

            return new Bitmap(
                bmpData.Width,
                bmpData.Height,
                bmpData.Stride,
                PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb,
                bmpData.Scan0);
        }

        return bmp;
    }

    private static bool IsAlphaBitmap(Bitmap bmp, out BitmapData bmpData)
    {
        Rectangle bmpBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

        bmpData = bmp.LockBits(bmpBounds, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

        try
        {
            return IsAlphaBitmap(bmpData);
        }
        finally
        {
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        }
    }

    private static bool IsAlphaBitmap(BitmapData bmpData)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= bmpData.Height - 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= bmpData.Width - 1; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = Color.FromArgb(
                    Marshal.ReadInt32(bmpData.Scan0, (bmpData.Stride * y) + (4 * x)));

                if (pixelColor.A > 0 & pixelColor.A < 255)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Ok, I know that the line `GC.SuppressFinalize(bmp);` has no sense, but when I remove that line, sometimes (each 4 or 5 calls) I get the following exception:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

I suspect that the garbage is collecting the bmp object before the return bitmap is drawn, so it try to access to the bits that are disposed by the framework. If I never collect the bmp it works, but it causes a memory leak (the bmp reference is never collected).

Do you know how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the remakrs for the [Bitmap constructor you are using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx)

> The caller is responsible for allocating and freeing the block of memory specified by the scan0 parameter. **However, the memory should not be released until the related Bitmap is released.**

This means that you need to make sure that you keep hold of the underlying block of memory that `bmpData` is pointing to until after the `Bitmap` instance returned by `GetBitmapFromHBitmap` is released.

Your problem is caused because the garbage collector has detected that `bmp` is unreachable (isn't being used) and so collects / finalizes it which **definitely** releases the underlying block of memory, however even if you suppress the finalizer you have still called `UnlockBits` which means that `bmpData` is already invalid anyway - it might work at the moment but thats completely down to chance. In order to make the above code correct you need to find a mechanism of keeping `bmpData` (and by extension `bmp`) valid for as long as the returned `Bitmap` instance is around - i.e. possibly a significant change to your application.

Alternatively see [Converting Bitmap PixelFormats in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016406/converting-bitmap-pixelformats-in-c-sharp) for a completely different way of doing (I think) what you want to achieve while avoiding all of these problems entirely.